# using different libc++ versions on travis for clang

Tags: c++, makefile, travis-ci, apt-get, libc++

Travis uses Ubuntu Trusty and the default libc++ version there is `svn199600`.

However I would like to test with different (newer) versions as I already do with different clang versions.

My current [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/blob/425c16140d28a32a8aa7e69d558d47efc5f48389/.travis.yml) looks as follows:

```
language: generic

dist: trusty
sudo: required

matrix:
    include:
    - env: CXX=g++-7 CC=gcc-7
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - g++-7
          sources: &sources
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
            - llvm-toolchain-precise
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.9
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.7
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.6
            - sourceline: 'deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main'
              key_url: 'http://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key'
    - env: CXX=g++-6 CC=gcc-6
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - g++-6
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - g++-5
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=g++-4.9 CC=gcc-4.9
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - g++-4.9
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=clang++-4.0 CC=clang-4.0
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-4.0
            - libc++-dev
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=clang++-3.9 CC=clang-3.9
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-3.9
            - libc++-dev
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=clang++-3.8 CC=clang-3.8
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-3.8
            - libc++-dev
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=clang++-3.7 CC=clang-3.7
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-3.7
            - libc++-dev
          sources: *sources
    - env: CXX=clang++-3.6 CC=clang-3.6
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - clang-3.6
            - libc++-dev
          sources: *sources

script:
    - ./build_and_test.sh

before_install:
    - ./before_install.sh
```

Replacing `libc++-dev` with `libc++-dev-3.9` for example does not help (still uses old library version), even when adding the following line:

```
- sourceline: 'deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main'
```

I also attempted to add the following to my `before_install.sh` without success (also still old library):

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main"   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install -y libc++-dev libc++-helpers libc++1 libc++abi-dev lldb-3.9
```

How is it done correctly without building from source?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't help"? Does the build fail? Does it build with the wrong library? Does this work for you locally without uninstall `libc++-dev` first?

Comment: @kichik Thanks for the remark. The problem is it still builds with the old library. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: on your env: lines, you can provide `LDFLAGS="-L /path/to/libary" LDLIBS="-l :libc++-dev-3.9.so"` for example to find that lib in the path given to LDFLAGS (presuming it's a .so file, in any case because I use a colon preceding the name in LDLIBS, it must be the exact filename, so it may be .a if statically linked).  I personally don't use travis, but the env lines looked like makefile stuff, and the above vars are used with Makefiles, so hope that works.

Comment: @strobelight Thanks, I also tried this, but it did not change anything.

Comment: I don't think this is travis related at all. Like strobelight said: You have to provide parameters to the build script and ensure it picks up the right library. If your build script does not user the LDFLAGS LDLIBS variables you have to look at the build script and find out what they are called or you have to add them.

Comment: @fhossfel: OK, perhaps it is more like a general question regarding Ubuntu Trusty. However in the end I need a travis configuration. ;)

Comment: If your build script supports picking the library via env variables the Travis config is pretty self-explanatory. BTW: Isn't that you want to achieve one of the few good use cases for Docker?

Comment: @fhossfel I have not worked with Docker yet. Perhaps I should start learning it. ;)

Comment: Can you show your Makefile?

Comment: @fhossfel Sure, it is all on [github/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus](https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to do it without building from source. The [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library uses [a script](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/install_libcxx.sh) doing exactly this.

I adjusted my `travis.yml` to use it too:

```
language: generic

dist: trusty
sudo: required

matrix:
    include:
    - os: linux
      compiler: gcc
      env: GCC_VERSION=7
        - CC=gcc-7
        - CXX=g++-7
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test']
          packages: ['g++-7']

    - os: linux
      compiler: gcc
      env: GCC_VERSION=6
        - CC=gcc-6
        - CXX=g++-6
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test']
          packages: ['g++-6']

    - os: linux
      compiler: gcc
      env: GCC_VERSION=5
        - CC=gcc-5
        - CXX=g++-5
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test']
          packages: ['g++-5']

    - os: linux
      compiler: clang
      env: CLANG_VERSION=5.0 LIBCXX=On
        - CC=clang-5.0
        - CXX=clang++-5.0
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0']
          packages: ['clang-5.0', 'g++-6']

    - os: linux
      compiler: clang
      env: CLANG_VERSION=4.0 LIBCXX=On
        - CC=clang-4.0
        - CXX=clang++-4.0
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0']
          packages: ['clang-4.0', 'g++-6']

    - os: linux
      compiler: clang
      env: CLANG_VERSION=3.9 LIBCXX=On
        - CC=clang-3.9
        - CXX=clang++-3.9
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9']
          packages: ['clang-3.9', 'g++-6']

    - os: linux
      compiler: clang
      env: CLANG_VERSION=3.8 LIBCXX=On
        - CC=clang-3.8
        - CXX=clang++-3.8
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test', 'llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.8']
          packages: ['clang-3.8', 'g++-6']

before_install:
  - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onqtam/doctest/master/doctest/doctest.h
  - sudo mv ./doctest.h /usr/local/include/doctest.h
  - |
    if [ -n "$GCC_VERSION" ]; then
      export CXX="g++-${GCC_VERSION}" CC="gcc-${GCC_VERSION}"
    fi
    if [ -n "$CLANG_VERSION" ]; then
      export CXX="clang++-${CLANG_VERSION}" CC="clang-${CLANG_VERSION}"
    fi
    if [ "$LIBCXX" == "On" ]; then
      sudo apt-get purge cmake
      sudo apt-get install cmake3
      cmake --version
      sudo CXX="$CXX" CC="$CC"
      sudo ./cmake/install_libcxx.sh
      export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
    fi

install:
  - mkdir -p build && cd build
  - cmake .. -DUNITTEST=ON

script:
  - which $CXX
  - $CXX --version
  - cmake --build . --target unittest --config Release -- -j4
```